# Share Online Curl PHP FileUpload API, MD5 not Fetchable

Tags: curl, file-upload

I tried many different requests, i also changes files location and relativa absolute path. maybe someone have the time to help me please.
Im new to curl file uploads.
The uplaod form, api example work, but maybe im missing soemthing why this curl dont work,there api is to less info its only a form as an example: http://www.share-online.biz/uploadapi/

here is the support ticket, but this dont help:
https://www.share-online.biz/helpdesk/ticket.php?track=LPDZM15R71&Refresh=20388

as a result im getting:
Server/Sessionid
dlw274-1.share-online.biz/upload
AH1HBU0PC1A549

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 08:55:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false

*** EXCEPTION md5 not fetchable - 12-12-2017, 8:55 am ***

HERE the Code:

```html
function shareonlinebizupload($filelocation,$user, $pass, $servername,$sessionname){
    $fpost = array();
    $fpost["username"] = $user;
    $fpost["password"] = $pass;
    $fpost["upload_session"] = $sessionname;
    $fpost['chunk_no'] = '1';
    $fpost['chunk_number'] = '1';
    $fpost['filesize'] = "2693093";
    $fpost["finalize"] = "1";
    $fpost['fn'] = "@/Desktoppe.rar";

    $server = "http://$servername";
    $page = curl_func($server,$fpost,'','',0);
    echo $page;
}
function curl_func($link, $postfields = '', $cookie = '', $refer = '', $header = 1, $follow = 1, $usragent = ''){
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    if($header){
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));}
    else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);}
    if($follow){
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);}
    else{
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);}
    if($usragent){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $usragent);}
    else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');}

    if($refer){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refer);}

    if($postfields){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    }
    if($cookie){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(empty($page)){
        echo "<br/>Could not connect to host: <br/> $link <br/>";
        //die();
    }
    else{
        return $page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in the same upload script. The behaviour has change since PHP 5.5.0. You need to use [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) for the files.
Replace

```
$fpost['fn'] = "@/Desktoppe.rar";
```

with

```
$fpost['fn'] = new CurlFile("/Desktoppe.rar");
```

That should do the trick :)